# How to get a list of households registered to an account with c# and sonos api?

Tags: c#, sonos

This is my method

```
static public async Task<string> Get(string token, string url)
{
     HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
     using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url))
     {
         request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
         request.Headers.Host = "api.ws.sonos.com";
         var response = await httpclient.SendAsync(request);
         response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
         return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     }
}
```

and this is how I call it in my main

```
namespace ApiTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ApiConnect.Get("My Access Token", "https://api.ws.sonos.com/control/api/v3/households").Result);
```

I'm try to get the list of households registered to my account but I get a 404 error.

Comment: NEVER create a new HttpClient for each request.  https://josef.codes/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/

Comment: Have you read the API documentation?

Comment: the API documentation is in curl, which I know nothing about.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending your client key or setting the content type to json.